# Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.14.1/linux-arm64-79_binding.node": / 404 Error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http-status-code-404, node-sass

Please understand that I am not good at English, so I use the translator.
There is a frontend project that is being developed as react.
If you run this project through the npm run start command, it will run normally.
However, when running in a docker environment through the docker-compose up command, it does not run with the following error log displayed in the RUN npm install part:
For your information, I am using the m1 MacBook environment.

```
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.3s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.5s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:13.14.0-alpine                                                                                                                                                                                           2.4s
 => [1/9] FROM docker.io/library/node:13.14.0-alpine@sha256:01254fbce7320d80f46b9dbfc0620af50c67c4319aff1e53436aea7dbabc8bc0                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.4s
 => => transferring context: 9.60MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.2s
 => CACHED [2/9] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [3/9] COPY package.json ./                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [4/9] RUN apk add curl                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [5/9] RUN apk add lsof                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [6/9] RUN apk add git                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [7/9] RUN npm install -g dotenv-cli react-scripts@3.4.1 --silent                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => ERROR [8/9] RUN npm install --silent                                                                                                                                                                                                                        88.7s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 > [8/9] RUN npm install --silent:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
#12 84.88 husky > Setting up git hooks                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
#12 84.90 git rev-parse command failed. Got fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git                                                                                                                                                      
#12 84.90 husky > Failed to install                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#12 85.95 Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.14.1/linux-arm64-79_binding.node                                                                                                                                             
#12 86.70 Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.14.1/linux-arm64-79_binding.node": 
#12 86.70 
#12 86.70 HTTP error 404 Not Found
#12 86.70 
#12 86.70 Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
#12 86.70       try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g. 
#12 86.70 
#12 86.70       export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234
#12 86.70 
#12 86.70 or configure npm proxy via
#12 86.70 
#12 86.70       npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
#12 87.52 Building: /usr/local/bin/node /app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
#12 87.63 gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
#12 87.63 gyp verb cli [
#12 87.63 gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
#12 87.63 gyp verb cli   '/app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
#12 87.63 gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
#12 87.63 gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
#12 87.63 gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
#12 87.63 gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
#12 87.63 gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
#12 87.63 gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
#12 87.63 gyp verb cli ]
#12 87.63 gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
#12 87.63 gyp info using node@13.14.0 | linux | arm64
#12 87.63 gyp verb command rebuild []
#12 87.63 gyp verb command clean []
#12 87.64 gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
#12 87.64 gyp verb command configure []
#12 87.64 gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
#12 87.64 gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
#12 87.64 gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
#12 87.64 gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
#12 87.64 gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
#12 87.64 gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
#12 87.64 gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
#12 87.64 gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
#12 87.64 gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:171:21)
#12 87.64 gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
#12 87.64 gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
#12 87.64 gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
#12 87.64 gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
#12 87.64 gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
#12 87.64 gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
#12 87.64 gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
#12 87.64 gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:171:21) {
#12 87.64 gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
#12 87.64 gyp verb `which` failed }
#12 87.64 gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
#12 87.65 gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
#12 87.65 gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
#12 87.65 gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
#12 87.65 gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
#12 87.65 gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
#12 87.65 gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
#12 87.65 gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
#12 87.65 gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:171:21)
#12 87.65 gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
#12 87.65 gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
#12 87.65 gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
#12 87.65 gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
#12 87.65 gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
#12 87.65 gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
#12 87.65 gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
#12 87.65 gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:171:21) {
#12 87.65 gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
#12 87.65 gyp verb `which` failed }
#12 87.65 gyp ERR! configure error 
#12 87.65 gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
#12 87.65 gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
#12 87.65 gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
#12 87.65 gyp ERR! stack     at F (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
#12 87.65 gyp ERR! stack     at E (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
#12 87.65 gyp ERR! stack     at /app/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
#12 87.65 gyp ERR! stack     at /app/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
#12 87.65 gyp ERR! stack     at /app/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
#12 87.65 gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:171:21)
#12 87.65 gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.121-linuxkit
#12 87.65 gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
#12 87.65 gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/node-sass
#12 87.65 gyp ERR! node -v v13.14.0
#12 87.65 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
#12 87.65 gyp ERR! not ok 
#12 87.65 Build failed with error code: 1
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install --silent]: exit code: 1
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `python --version`?

Comment: Paython version is 2.7.16